# Ethernet/UIB device is accessible on one system but not the other (Linux)

Tags: linux, debian, ethernet

A Universal Interface Board connects to the computer via Ethernet.
On a correctly configured system (A), arp -a lists its MAC address and establishes a connection. The connection appears to happen through/dev/ttyACM0

```
arp -a
...
(10.0.0.100) at d8:80:39:27:d5:4b [ether] on eth1
...
```

On the other system (B), the device is visible, yet its MAC address is hidden and it is not possible to establish a connection.

```
arp -a
... 
(10.0.0.100) at <incomplete> on eth2
...
```

Even more interestingly, when I connect the UIB to A, then disconnect and connect to B, the connection to the UIB is established.

/etc/network/interfaces of A:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth1
#allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet static
  address 10.0.0.1
  netmask 255.255.0.0
  network 10.0.0.0
  broadcast 10.0.255.255
  post-up /usr/bin/logger -p syslog.info $0 eth1 up

auto eth1:0
#allow-hotplug eth1:0
iface eth1:0 inet static
  address 192.168.0.50
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  network 192.168.0.0
  broadcast 192.168.0.255

# The primary network interface auto eth0
#auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

iface eth0:0 inet static
  address 192.168.1.99
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  network 192.168.1.0
  broadcast 192.168.1.255
  gateway 192.168.1.1
#  dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
#  post-up ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 table classic-route
#  post-up ip rule add fwmark 0x1 table classic-route

#auto eth0:1
#allow-hotplug eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
  address 192.168.6.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  network 192.168.6.0
  broadcast 192.168.6.255

#access pi3 on eth0 at 192.168.5.254
#auto eth0:2
#allow-hotplug eth0:2
iface eth0:2 inet static
  address 192.168.5.2
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  network 192.168.5.0
  broadcast 192.168.5.255

allow-hotplug usb0
iface usb0 inet static
  address 192.168.4.2
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  network 192.168.4.0
  broadcast 192.168.4.255

# eth2 tablet on usb
#auto eth2
allow-hotplug eth2
iface eth2 inet static
  address 10.2.0.1
  netmask 255.255.0.0
  network 10.2.0.0
  broadcast 10.2.255.255
```

Network setup for B:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#auto eth2
allow-hotplug eth2
iface eth2 inet static
address 10.0.0.1
netmask 255.255.0.0
network 10.0.0.0
broadcast 10.0.255.255

#auto eth3
allow-hotplug eth3
iface eth3 inet dhcp
```

Comment: Why do you say it is not possible to establish a connection?

Comment: First, the MAC address is incomplete (on successful connection it becomes visible), second of all, on launching the interacting-with-UIB program the UIB does not flash green (meaning it is receiving output) or otherwise respond.